# jQuery in .Net - Adding Rows to a table and then accessing them?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have 5 dropdowns in a table in my asp .net app, and I'm using jQuery to add and remove rows of those 5 dropdowns dynamically. I've got the functionality working in terms of the UI, but the example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/781851/Add-Delete-Rows-Dynamically-using-jQuery-in-ASP-NE uses fileupload in the current http context for enumerating access to the controls, and since there is only one fileupload control per row that makes it easy.

I am completely stumped how to access each row's 5 dropdown controls I have in a loop, so i can set the values in a List.

Code:

```
<div>
            <table id="Table1" cellspacing="3">
                <tr class="rowstyle">
                    <td>Disk Count: 
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDiskCount1">
                            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>41</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>42</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>43</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>44</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>46</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>47</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>48</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Disk Type:
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDiskType1">
                            <asp:ListItem>SAS</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>SATA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>SSD</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Disk Size in GB:
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDiskSizeInGB1">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="120">120GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2400">240GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="300">300GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="600">600GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="900">900GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1000">1000GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1200">1200GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1600">1600GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2000">2000GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3000">3000GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4000">4000GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="5000">5000GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="6000">6000GB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="8000">8000GB</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Disk Speed:
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDiskSpeed1">
                            <asp:ListItem>15K</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>SSD</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>10K</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>7.2K</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5.4K</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Disk Size:
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDiskPhysicalSize1">
                            <asp:ListItem>2.5</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3.5</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1.8</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="BtnPlus" value="+" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="BtnMinus" value="-" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>      
        </div>     
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

My jQuery Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ID = 2;
            function addRow() {
                var html =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Disk Count: <select name="ddlDiskCount' + ID + '" ><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option><option>32</option><option>33</option><option>34</option><option>35</option><option>36</option><option>37</option><option>39</option><option>40</option><option>41</option><option>42</option><option>43</option><option>44</option><option>45</option><option>46</option><option>47</option><option>48</option></select></td>' +
                    '<td>Disk Type: <select name="ddlDiskType' + ID + '" ><option>SAS</option><option>SATA</option><option>SSD</option></select></td>' +
                    '<td>Disk Size in GB: <select name="ddlDiskSizeInGB' + ID + '" > <option value=120>120GB</option><option value=240>240GB</option><option value=300>300GB</option><option value=600>600GB</option><option value=900>900GB</option><option value=1000>1000GB</option><option value=1200>1200GB</option><option value=1600>1600GB</option><option value=2000>2000GB</option><option value=3000>3000GB</option><option value=4000>4000GB</option><option value=5000>5000GB</option><option value=6000>6000GB</option><option value=8000>8000GB</option></select></td>' +
                    '<td>Disk Speed: <select name="ddlDiskSpeed' + ID + '" > <option>15K</option><option>SSD</option><option>10K</option><option>7.2K</option><option>5.4K</option></select></td>' +
                    '<td>Disk Size: <select name="ddlDiskPhysicalSize' + ID + '" > <option>2.5</option><option>3.5</option><option>1.8</option></select></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="button" class="BtnPlus" value="+" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="button" class="BtnMinus" value="-" /></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                $(html).appendTo($("#Table1"))
                ID++;
            };
            $("#Table1").on("click", ".BtnPlus", addRow);
            function deleteRow() {
                var par = $(this).parent().parent();
                par.remove();
            };
            $("#Table1").on("click", ".BtnMinus", deleteRow);
        });
</script>
```

Where I'm stumped:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {


    }
}
```

(I can clearly not use this.Context.Request.Files to enumerate each row)...